# My Bottom Navigation from Material Design for Android is showing me one item more than it should

Tags: android, xml, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to implement Bottom Navigation and its showing me one more item than should(I have 5 items in my bottom_navigation_menu.xml and its one more black in effect)
[here its screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLpy9.png)

What I am missing?
What is wrong?

There is my main_activity.xml(btw. why "Hello world is not in center?):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />



</LinearLayout>
```

and bottom_navigation_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:title="@string/favorites"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_music"
        android:title="@string/music"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_3"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_places"
        android:title="@string/places"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_4"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_new"
        android:title="@string/news"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_5"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="@string/profile"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen wrong ViewGroup.
Use ConstraintLayout and align bottom nav at the bottom via constraints or use RelativeLayout.
You are using LinearLayout and orientation horizontal. For that reason you are seeing black space

Comment: With RelativeLayout I must use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". This will not be a problem in future?
And also can you told me how to change position of that text? Also something like with this Bottom Navigation?

Comment: I recommend ConstraintLayout. There won't be problem if child views count will not increase

Comment: Ok, how I should align Bottom Navigation with constrainst using ConstraintLayout, its not obvious for me, even with what Android Studio is proposing.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout